# How to Use Predicate in a Switch Statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiwebview

(Apologies if this is an obvious answer, I am very new to programming.)

I have a mutable array defined with different types of fabrics. What I'd like to do is compare a string entered by a user in a text box to the objects in the array. Then, depending on the value of the string, I'll display a different picture in a UIWebView. (The reason I went with arrays was because I read you can't do Switch statements with strings.) So I set up a predicate to search the array.

However, I can't figure out how to go from the Predicate to the Index value of that object, to use in the switch statement.

Should I be following a different tactic? Is this even possible?

```
-(IBAction)btnAddFabric:(id)sender
 {

  myFabrics = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cotton",@"Fleece",@"Linen",@"Nylon",
                      @"Polyester",@"Rayon",@"Silk",@"Spandex",@"Suede",@"Wool",nil];
  NSString *fabricType;

  fabricType = self.txtType.text;

  self.lblFabric1.text = fabricType;

  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains     
     %d",fabricType];
  NSArray *result = [myFabrics filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


  switch (result)
   {
     case 0:
      imageURLString=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<Picture of cotton fabric from    
         Google here>"];
      break

   }

   [self.fabricPic loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL];
}
```

Comment: look up `indexOfObject:` in the NSArray docs.

Comment: Multiple issues here that are going to cause you trouble, starting with passing a string to %d in the predicateWithFormat constructor, then you're trying to pass an NSArray to switch which only works on integral values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)btnAddFabric:(id)sender
 {

  myFabrics = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cotton",@"Fleece",@"Linen",@"Nylon",
                      @"Polyester",@"Rayon",@"Silk",@"Spandex",@"Suede",@"Wool",nil];
  NSString *fabricType;

  fabricType = self.txtType.text;

  self.lblFabric1.text = fabricType;

  int result=[myFabrics indexOfObject:fabricType];


  switch (result)
   {
     case 0:
      imageURLString=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<Picture of cotton fabric from    
         Google here>"];
      break

   }

   [self.fabricPic loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL];
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Also this is me right now: http://media3.giphy.com/media/mcMNAiDvn9tTO/giphy.gif

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an array and a switch statement, use a dictionary where the keys are your fabric types / names and the associated values are the URL strings.

Now, use the predicate to filter the keys (use `allKeys` to get the array of keys) and then use the resulting key to get the URL string value from the dictionary.

Also, do you really need to use a predicate? Consider just showing the list of fabrics, for example in a table view, and directly using the selected item to access the dictionary. If you want you can add a search controller to the table view - this brings the predicate back in, but to filter to a list of results rather than directly to one result like you're currently trying to do.

Comment: I did think about using a table/drop list, but I only know how to do a single-view application and I admit... I don't know how to deal with table views. I really don't need to use a predicate, I just couldn't come up with any better way of accessing the information.

Comment: Start a new project with a master-detail template. This will give you the structure for a table view, and on selection opening a detail view. Then you just need to fill in your fabrics and pass the URL string to the detail view to show the image... (even if you just use this as an experiment / to learn)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems here including:

1. passing a NSString to %d, use %@ instead
2. passing an NSArray to switch, it only takes integral values
3. the query is case dependent and won't match "blue cotton"

To fix them try and modify to suit.

```
-(IBAction)btnAddFabric:(id)sender
{
    NSArray*    myFabrics = @[@"Cotton",@"Fleece",@"Linen",@"Nylon",
                              @"Polyester",@"Rayon",@"Silk",@"Spandex",@"Suede",@"Wool"];

    NSString *fabricType;

    fabricType = self.txtType.text;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ CONTAINS[c] SELF",fabricType];
    NSArray *result = [myFabrics filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if(result.count != 0)
    {
        switch ([myFabrics indexOfObject:result[0]])
        {
            case 0:
                imageURLString=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<Picture of cotton fabric from Google here>"];
                break;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        // do something because it doesn't match a known fabric type
    }

    [self.fabricPic loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL]];
}
```